# How to convert csv string data into excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a string which contains the data in the form of csv. Now, I want to convert it to excel file. How could i do that ? Can anyone help me.

`String csvItem = "";`

`var sb = new StringBuilder();`

`//logic that appending the data`

`csvItem = sb.toString();`

Now data is like , example

Employee, Id

Varsha,12

John,13

Comment: You can use Epplus or automation and OpenText(). Also, excel opens the CSV natively. Using Excel as database is not a good idea.

Comment: I feel you misunderstood or I wrote the wrong statement.. I want to convert my csvItem string value into excel file. You can find the example i have provided

Comment: I think you don't understand what I am saying. With Epplus for example, instead of creating a string with your items you simply create a collection. Maybe I should give a sample. I will do in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Excel can open CSV files natively so you really don't *have* to convert the file to Excel. But if you really need to, what I use to create Excel Sheets is EP Plus. There's no need to build the StringBuilder string if you're going to do this. If you already have it in one string, you'll have to first split by line breaks (possibly using `csvItem.Split(Environment.NewLine)`). I don't know how you're building `sb` so I can't really help with that.

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");

    int rowCount = 1; // cols and rows in EP plus start at one not zero
    foreach (string line in XXX) { // foreach loop that goes through every line in your CSV data and sets each line to string "line"
        int colCount = 1;
        string[] lineData = line.Split(','); // split your line by comma
        foreach (string colValue in lineData) {
            worksheet.Cells[rowCount,colCount++].Value = colValue;
        }
        
        rowCount++;
    }

    // when you're done save your file
    var fi = new FileInfo(@"filename.xlsx");
    package.SaveAs(fi);
}
```

Comment: If you see the example i have provided , you will get an idea. I am actually storing into sb by just using sb.appendline(name + "," + id) by looping my data

Comment: Like I said then you'll need to split by Environment.NewLine.

Comment: I am a beginner,  and  I am not sure how could i use it store the csvItem into excel . If possible can you help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `string[] lines = csvItem.Split(Environment.NewLine;` this will give you an array of lines you can plug into the part where it says `XXX` in the `foreach` of the original answer.

Comment: I don't think an answer recommending a paid product to solve the problem actually solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This example use Epplus. (You don't need to create a string with StringBuilder for a CSV anyway, you could directly write to a CSV.)

```
void Main()
{
  var Employee = new List<Employee> {
   new Employee { Id=1, Name="Ali", Surname="Veli"},
   new Employee { Id=2, Name="Ahmet", Surname="Sari"},
   new Employee { Id=3, Name="Mehmet", Surname="Lacivert"},
   new Employee { Id=4, Name="Huseyin", Surname="En"},
   new Employee { Id=5, Name="Veli", Surname="Buyuk"},
   new Employee { Id=6, Name="Zeki", Surname="Fener"},
  };


  ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();

  var wsEnum = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Employees");
  wsEnum.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(Employee, true, TableStyles.Medium9);
  wsEnum.Cells[wsEnum.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

  var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\ExcelEmployee.xlsx");
  if (fi.Exists)
  {
    fi.Delete();
  }
  pck.SaveAs(fi);
}

public class Employee
{ 
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```